# Paginate, custom filter, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I'm creating a list of objects with some embedded html and I added a filter, but by what they see something wrong I want to throw me out please.

This is the example to pagination: [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/79yrgwiwvan3bAG5SnKx?p=preview)

**

### It is supposed to display a list with paging due and applying the filter.

**

```js
angular.module('App', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource'])
.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',
 function($scope){
  $scope.items=[
   {id: '1', title: '<b>Chicago</b>'},
   {id: '2', title: '<b><i>New York</i></b>'},
   {id: '3', title: '<div><p>London</p></div>'},
   {id: '4', title: '<div><p>Washington</p></div>'},
   {id: '5', title: '<div><p>Hawai</p></div>'},
   {id: '6', title: '<div><p>Dinamarca</p></div>'},
   {id: '7', title: '<div><p>Peru</p></div>'},
   {id: '8', title: '<div><p>USA</p></div>'},
   {id: '9', title: '<div><p>Ecuador</p></div>'},
   {id: '10', title: '<div><p>Japon</p></div>'}
  ];

  $scope.totalItems = $scope.objects.length;
  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.numPerPage = 5;

  $scope.paginate = function(value) {
   var begin, end, index;
   begin = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage;
   end = begin + $scope.numPerPage;
   index = $scope.objects.indexOf(value);
   return (begin <= index && index < end);
  };
 }
])

.filter("htmlToPlaintext", function() {
 return function(text) {
 return text.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter : paginate">
   {{item.title|htmlToPlaintext}}
  </div>
  <pagination total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage"
 max-size="5" boundary-links="true"
 items-per-page="numPerPage" class="pagination-lg">
 </pagination>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *by what they see something wrong I want to throw me out please*. What does that mean? What is the concrete problem? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: It is supposed to display a list with paging due and applying the filter.

Comment: the plunker provided here is working fine

Comment: The problem is not the plunker, the problem is the snippet

Comment: so the "<div><p>London</p></div>" needs to be formated /filter to "London" is it ? If it is the case then text.replace(......) in your case is not right.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your questions right ( I did modify the  PLUNKR  , may be you want to strip the html elements and just want the text within). Your filter, the way it is written, will strip everything and will return "".Assuming that inputs to the filter will be html content and you want show the perceived text of the html.

Try the following

```
 .filter("htmlToPlaintext", function() {
    return function(text) {
       var htmlNode = document.createElement('div'); 
       htmlNode.innerHTML = text;
       return htmlNode.innerText;
    }
});
```